# VS code Runs previous file instead current one

Tags: python, html, visual-studio-code, ide

[I clicked run on python file, but it keep on opening the previous html file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bezIz.jpg)

I clicked run from python file in vs code but the terminal is not running (which usually happens before) and the vs code is keep on opening the html file that i opened as previous file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a temp solution you can write to the terminal the code you want to run (like in CMD).

Be sure you are at the correct directory and than type: `python name_of_code.py` and it should run it.

For exmp.

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python\My_Dicrectory> python my_code.py
```

Comment: I usually press F5 to run, but now it is opening the same file again and again not the current file.

Answer (score 0):

cause you select `Launch:index`:

[image]

select `Python:Current File` will solve your problem:

[image]

Comment: I could not find the options in drop down menu, it only shows Launch: Index.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: Its the .vscode folder added to the same folder with Json file in it. It keeps on overriding the current file in the folder. Thanks all